# Multiple items as a foreign key Django Models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of creating an e-commerce website with the django framework and have run into some problems with my models.
Basically, this is a company which sells bags containing numerous different childrens toys. I've created a slugged page that users can access for more information about each toy and I want to have a list of toys that can be added to a bag, so that the same toy can be in 2 different bags. This way, the same toy object can be used multiple times if bags share a toy.

I have managed to link one toy to a bag thus far, using a foreign key in the models. However, I'm not sure how to modify my code so that I can have multiple toy objects connected to a bag object.

```
class Contents(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contents, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Above is the code I have so far for the toys model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    pk_num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Contents, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'items'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is the code I have for the Bags.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a many-to-many field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `field.ManyToManyField` https://www.docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many.

The one toy can be assigned to multiple bags and vice versa one bag can be assigned to multiple toys.